# Xcode 4.3 names completion

Tags: xcode4.3

In Xcode 4.2 when you start typing a method, or any known name, the options similar to what you are typing pops up.. and if you hit the right arow on the keyboard it works like you were typing the letters of the selected sugestion...

In Xcode 4.3, in this same situtaion, if you hit the right key on the keyboard it acts like a normal right key, like a space bar.. and doesnt keep filling the letters of the sugested phrase.

Anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the tab key that should complete the next chunk

Comment: but i dont want to complete the whole junk.. i just want to complete letter by letter with right arrow key.. like it was in xcode 4.2